# Setting default image style to 'original image' in formatter

Tags: 7, entities, media

In a custom formatter that I'm writing, I have a problem with default_value for an image style.

```
function MYMODULE_field_formatter_info() {
  return array(
    'MYMODULE_formatter' => array(
      'label' => t('My Custom Formatter'),
      'field types' => array('image'),
      'multiple values' => FIELD_BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT,
      'settings' => array(
        'trigger_image_style' => '',
      )
    ),
  );
}


function MYMODULE_field_formatter_settings_form($field, $instance, $view_mode, $form, &$form_state){
  $display = $instance['display'][$view_mode];
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  $element = array();

  $image_styles = image_style_options(FALSE);
  $element['trigger_image_style'] =  array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Trigger image style:'),
    '#description' => t('Image style to be used for trigger'),
    '#default_value' => $settings['trigger_image_style'],
    '#options' => $image_styles,
  );

  return $element;
}

function MYMODULE_field_formatter_view($entity_type, $entity, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $display) {
  $elements = array();
  $html = "";
  $settings = $display['settings'];

  // ensure deaults?
  if (!isset($settings['trigger_image_style'])) $settings['trigger_image_style'] = '';
  //.....
}
```

Seems that Drupal will return incorrect path:

```
image_style_url($settings['trigger_image_style'], $item['uri']);
```

until I explicitly set a style of my choice. The incorrect path will have double slash, as in:

```
http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles//public/trigger-images/test1.jpg
```

I thought that empty string simply means 'use original image'... How should I tell Drupal to use original image if the style is not set or is an empty string?

Comment: Why you left Drupal ?

Answer (score 1):

It is have simple solution when you want specified `image_style` use something like

```
  image_style_url('850x450',$file->uri);
```

and when you don't want use any image style and want use origin image use

```
 file_create_url($file->uri);
```